# How do I prevent duplicate indexing by Googlebot-Mobile?

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, user-agent, googlebot-mobile

I have only one version of my web-site, and it is optimised for both the desktop and the smartphone.

I've noticed that Google crawls each page exactly twice: once with `Googlebot/2.1`, and again with `Googlebot-Mobile/2.1`:

```
% fgrep "/www/drupal6/filefield " /var/www/logs/ports.su/ports.su.access.log
66.249.76.223 - - [12/Mar/2013:07:46:42 -0700] "GET /www/drupal6/filefield HTTP/1.1" 200 2365 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.76.223 - - [12/Mar/2013:13:59:23 -0700] "GET /www/drupal6/filefield HTTP/1.1" 200 2365 "-" "DoCoMo/2.0 N905i(c100;TB;W24H16) (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I don't think blocking either of these bots in `/robots.txt` would be appropriate, as it might remove my site from their respective index.

However, don't they share their indices, too?

How do I tell Google that I only have one site?

**Looking for something that's the opposite of [`Vary: User-Agent`](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/redirects).**

Comment: Why does this question has a -2?  Am I an idiot for expecting a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

**You are already telling them because you have one site using a single set of URLs.**

They visit twice because each bot evaluates differently. In the end it goes in the same index but the metadata is different which lets them serve different results to standard and mobile queries.

Comment: this is not an answer — the question is pretty clear that there is only one set of URLs to begin with.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, I meant this is *already* the case. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Having `Googlebot/2.1` and `Googlebot-Mobile/2.1` is a good thing, you should not block either.

It's important to note that when viewing Google search results on a mobile phone they tend to vary from a Desktop Google search since Google favors sites that are viewable on a mobile phone. Blocking `Googlebot-Mobile/2.1` may prevent people finding your site when they use Google search on their phone.

Comment: Yes, I agree that blocking does not sound like a solution.  But with 8k individual pages, it seems like a huge waste of resources to be requesting each page twice.  Note that the requests even come from the same IPv4-address over at Google.  The pages are static (re-generated daily) — why is Google downloading every page twice, instead of going forward with its indexing otherwise?  There should be a way to prevent this.

Comment: There is no work around for this as far as I know... In terms of Google using up your resources well you have the option of blocking them, otherwise you have to lump it... To be honest with good hosting you never have to be concerned with the usage of resources, your bandwidth and system resources should be budgeted into your daily visits which includes usage from bots otherwise you need to upgrade. The more popular your site is the more often Google will visit your site too, and again this is a good thing. You should have some kind of return of investment (ie ads) on the hosting for upgrades.